# C# Why is default constructor on new record struct defaulting to default(record)?

Tags: c#, code-generation, record

If I have a record defined as this:

```cs
    public record struct MyRecord(string Whatever = "anything"){
        public DateTime  Start {get; init;} = DateTime.UtcNow;
        public DateTime? End   {get; init;}
    }
```

and then in my code run `new MyRecord()`, the actual code generated for that is `default(MyRecord)`.

If I supply value for any of the values of the primary constructor (ie, in the parantheses) it correctly calls `new MyRecord(whatever)`.

In this case it leads to the Start value always being 0 ticks (ie 01/01/0001 00:00:00).

[SharpLabs](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFAEgpwGwAIoBYsCyAhgJYB2AFAJTIoDetKAbkQE5YAWWAvFmQKYB3QgE8ASvwDGAe1bBqAbkboAnBQ5UlqNHDVdBJAC5c6AUTLAeWACJFD/ACokAtvwB0AVUOSActMEAvliajLQBtFAAzFisUrKWAM6GrACukoaiEjJyFOgADFgA6hx2/Ez87LwARFVUDNpRNqVOrlgAyoZsGVh0AOb8hgpY5EYKQby29i3uXr7+bgCCwMC2IgkUALRwIQ3Rk44u/AD8WOaWfQNDI4PhqAFAA===)

Why is it doing this?

Comment: because it is a struct. that's how they behave. use a class and it will behave as you excepted

Comment: when I called `var record = new MyRecord("whatever");` method. it is giving the the correct datetime for `Start`. sorry didn't get your question

Comment: This is a special case of a more general issue in that the compiler will not attempt to detect and warn for the case where a type has both a default constructor, and a constructor with only default parameters -- in particular the case where that constructor has only one parameter, which is almost never meaningful as you can't call that constructor with its default (except through very artificial means). For a `class` this tends not to be a problem since you must explicitly declare the default constructor, so you can be presumed to know what you're doing, but for a `struct` you have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every struct implicitly has a parameter less instance constructor. Therefore, `new MyRecord()` calls this default constructor instead of your constructor with the optional string parameter.

See: [C# 7.0 draft specification / 15 Structs / 15.4 Class and struct differences / 15.4.5 Default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/structs#1545-default-values):

> [...] Instead, every struct implicitly has a parameterless instance constructor, which always returns the value that results from setting all fields to their default values.

Instead, write your own default constructor ([possible since C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#improvements-of-structure-types)):

```cs
public record struct MyRecord(string Whatever)
{
    public MyRecord()
        : this("anything") // Calls MyRecord(string Whatever)
    {
    }

    public DateTime Start { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `record struct` which is still a `struct`. When you call the default constructor , you're getting the default value for that struct, just like any other `struct`.

Structs always have a default constructor that's not the same as any constructor with default parameters. In structs without an explicit default constructor the compiler generates one that initializes all fields to their default values.

When you call `new MyRecord()` you're calling the default constructor generated by the compiler, not the `MyRecord(string)` constructor.

If you used this struct :

```
public  struct Point{
    public int X{get;init;}
    public int Y {get;init;}
    
    public Point(int x=3,int y=3)
    {
        X=x;
        Y=x;
    }            
}
static void Main()
{
    var h = new Point();
    Console.WriteLine(h);
    Console.WriteLine(h with {X = 45} );
    
}
```

You'd still get the default constructor:

```
    Point point = default(Point);
    Console.WriteLine(point);
    Point point2 = point;
    point2.X = 45;
    Console.WriteLine(point2);
```

If you want to override the default constructor you'll have to explicitly define one:

```
public  struct Point{
    public int X{get;init;}
    public int Y {get;init;}
    
    public Point()
    {
        X=4;
        Y=4;
    }
    public Point(int x=3,int y=3)
    {
        X=x;
        Y=x;
    }            
}
```

In this case SharpLab shows a call to the type's new default constructor :

```
    Point point = new Point();
    Console.WriteLine(point);
    Point point2 = point;
    point2.X = 45;
    Console.WriteLine(point2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the decompilation in your question, `record struct` is just a syntactic for `struct` "with benefits", so it follows the same rules for constructors, i.e. struct will always have a default one (unlike `class`es) and it will be preferred by overload resolution:

```cs
var h = new MyRecord();
Console.WriteLine(h.Whatever);
Console.WriteLine((h with {End = DateTime.UtcNow}).Whatever );

public struct MyRecord
{
    public MyRecord(string Whatever = "qwe"){this.Whatever = Whatever;}
    public string Whatever {get; init;}
    public DateTime Start  {get; init;} = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1);
    public DateTime? End {get; init;}
}
```

Results in the [same call](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDIG4EMBOACAFtgXmwDsBTAd2wFkBPAJVIGMB7TYACgEoBuZKOAJztcAOgDqudABdSqUph59B7YdnIBLKfgDeAUWLBC2ACLTSAFXUBbUiICqUxgDlm5AL6dxkmXJyKUSFAAzNgAzlKYAK6MUtT0TKzAyNrI2GnYwXEMLGzs/AAM2BJmvkYARACO5KRlnNpa6qFeJfJGxT7y3G6p6ZkFRd6yrdoA5qRS3NjqxJpdyACQmaYyljbYAMpSWLHYo+OT07NuRssW1rYOzq4iAILAwKY0oewAtHD+iyGnq6QA/Nj6Qx7CZTGYTbpINxAA=) to default ctor:

```cs
MyRecord myRecord = default(MyRecord);
Console.WriteLine(myRecord.Whatever);
MyRecord myRecord2 = myRecord;
myRecord2.End = DateTime.UtcNow;
Console.WriteLine(myRecord2.Whatever);
```